# How can range space be invariant?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

It is said that:

> Recall that if $T \in L(V)$ then the range $\operatorname{range}(T)=\{T(v) \mid v\in V\}$ is
>   invariant under $T$. This can easily be seen since if $u \in \operatorname{range}(T)$, then
>   $T(u) \in \operatorname{range}(T)$ by the definition of the subspace $\operatorname{range}(T)$.

Suppose I have a vector in 3D as $(x,y,z)$ and a linear transform is given by:
\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}

Then $\operatorname{null}(T)$ is $\{(0,0,1)\}$ and $\operatorname{range}(T)$ is $\{(1,0,0), (0,1,0)\}$.

Now according to the quote if I take "$u \in \operatorname{range}(T)$" as $u = (1,0,0)$ then 
Tu must be in $\operatorname{range}(T)$ but $Tu=(0,0,1)$ which is not in $\operatorname{range}(T)$.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've made a mistake: the range of $T$ is $\{(0,x,y)\mid x,y\in k\}$, to which $(1,0,0)$ does not belong.

Comment: I thought range(T) is all the vectors in the input space such that $T(v) \neq 0$. You are suggesting it is the output space ?

Comment: Yes, it is: $\operatorname{range}T=\{Tu\mid u\in k^3\}$.

Comment: So the theorem says: If I take an output vector of a transform, then as the transform can only map to range(T), the transform of that to can only map to range(T). I'm guessing 0 is in range(T) sealing the argument?

Comment: The fact that $0\in\operatorname{range}T$ is corret, but not relevant. By definition, $\operatorname{range}T$ consists of all vectors of the form $Tu$. In particular, if $u\in\operatorname{range}T$, then $Tu\in\operatorname{range}T$ too.

Comment: Isint it relevant?  T(Tu) could be 0. From your range space of (0,x,y), I pick (0,0,1) and T(0,0,1) = 0.

Comment: It is not relevant to the proof that $\operatorname{range}T$ is invariant under $T$.